# Dedicated server hosting with your own server

Tags: hosting, rackspace

Is that possible?

I notice that monthly prices go up when the more powerful your server.

I'd like to avoid the raise in pricing by using my own home-built rackable-server. I would like to send my sever to a hosting company that will manage it for me.

The monthly bill should only include the usage of rackspace and an internet connection. And also maintenance if I need the server manually restarted or something.

Any ideas? Am I crazy?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for colocation services: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocation_centre.

Comment: @joeqwerty I stole your answer as per: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931 =)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a "Colocation Environment" (or "Colo" for short) wherein you can rack up your own servers and appliances in someone else's datacenter cabinets. You are charged a flat fee for the rackspace and charged on some kind of scale for bandwidth. You may also be charged extra for electricity if your power needs are dense.